# What does the GTK Loader compiz plugin do?

Tags: unity, compiz, gtk, plugins

In `ccsm` there is a "GTK Loader" plugin. This is not used on a clean install.

What does it do? If it preloads GTK once like the tooltip implies then is it a good idea to turn it on?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience: **if you didn't manually turn it off then leave it off**. I found my water plugin broken by a combination of this, blur settings and who knows what GTK2 or 3 settings. (BTW...Dimming the window or screen for the duration of the effect...but no water at all...)

http://forum.compiz.org/viewtopic.php?t=2244 gave me a hint...and Google search for "compiz gtkloader plugin" settled it for me with:

https://code.launchpad.net/~vanvugt/unity/remove-gtkloader/+merge/109316

> **Sam Spilsbury (smspillaz) wrote on 2012-06-08:**    #
>
> To clarify - we can only initialize gtk+ once, and I'd prefer that we
>   don't do it in a distro patch. Because we'll be enabling sheet style
>   dialogues this cycle in a separate plugin, we need to have gtkloader
>   in a plugin that is guarunteed to load once, and before unityshell and
>   unitydialog.
>
> The reason why it existed in unityshell and in a distro patch in
>   compiz was purely historical - there was difficulty in enabling new
>   plugins on upgrades. That reason no longer exists - we have settings
>   upgrades in compizconfig to mantion that.
>
> **Daniel van Vugt (vanvugt) wrote on 2012-06-10:**    #
>
> BTW Sam, it now occurs to me that even if we do introduce any new
>   feature that requires gtk initialization, keeping gtkloader would not
>   make sense in any scenario:
>
> 1. The new feature was in lp:unity. In that case, gtk initialization is already done in unityshell and gtkloader is not required.
>
> or
>
> 1. The new feature goes outside of lp:unity, like lp:compiz or somewhere else. In that case, gtk initialization should go in the
>      project where the new feature is. And still, there is no reason to
>      keep gtkloader in lp:unity.